# Magnolia field check validation

Tags: validation, magnolia

I want to add the following functionality within a page's dialog.

Suppose you have text field A and text field B (to the dialog's yaml file). 
I want to make field B available for the author (input) only when text field A has content.

I know it is a straightforward problem but i am relatively new to magnolia.Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately fields are completely atomic and independent so there's no way of fields reacting to each other without rewriting `DialogPresenter` to make them aware of each other.
You can see example of how this can be done e.g. in `magnolia-external-form` module if you use enterprise version of Magnolia. Code for it is in Magnolia's git repo.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: thanks Jan , apart from the git is there any documentation with what steps to follow?

Comment: Not that i know of, but you might want to ask directly in Magnolia forum.